# Implementing Email Verification and Notification System in a Full-Stack Application with React Frontend and Node Backend

Tags: reactjs, node.js, rest, tracking

I have a full-stack application with a React frontend and a Node.js backend. In my application, I need to implement an email verification and notification system. Here's the workflow:

1. When a user provides their email, the application should send a secret verification link to the user's email address
2. Upon clicking the verification link, the backend should trigger another email notification to a different recipient
3. additionally, the backend needs to update the database to reflect the verification status

I'm looking for guidance on how to implement the second one in the workflow effectively in my application. I can send them to my website and they redirect. Is there any more efficient way to do that?

Any suggestions or examples of how to achieve this using libraries or frameworks commonly used in the React and Node.js ecosystem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!